# What do I put in my sessions controller in order to allow two models to login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, authentication, controller

So I am having trouble in my sessions controller. I am trying to allow users to signin and businessusers to signin. They both have their own respective model and table in the database. However only users can signin. This is my sessions controller currently. What can I add to the controller to allow businessusers to also signin?

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create

   customer = Customer.find_by_name(params[:name]) 
   if customer && customer.authenticate(params[:password])
   session[:customer_id] = customer.id  
   redirect_to customer
   else             
    flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid name/password combination."      
    render 'new'                  
 end

  end

  def destroy
    if signed_in?
        session[:customer_id] = nil         
        else
        flash[:notice] = "You need to sign in first"    
        end

     redirect_to signin_path
 end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    customer = Customer.find_by_name(params[:name]) 
    if customer.present? && customer.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_type] = 'Customer'
      session[:customer_id] = customer.id  
      redirect_to customer
    else
      businessuser = BusinessUser.find_by_name(params[:name])
      if businessuser.present? && businessuser.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_type] = 'Business'
        session[:businessuser_id] = businessuser.id  
        redirect_to businessuser
      else
        flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid name/password combination."      
        render 'new'                  
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if signed_in?
      session[:user_type] = nil
      session[:customer_id] = nil  
      session[:businessuser_id] = nil       
    else
      flash[:notice] = "You need to sign in first"    
    end

    redirect_to signin_path
  end
end
```